How to perform text to speech in python without blocking the main thread?
I basically want a logging system with text to speech in python but i am afraid it will pause the main program. Following program is working for me but it will pause thread where ever i log text to speech. Is there any way in python where i can log but it should not block main program.
import pyttsx3

class TextToSpeech:
    def textToSpeech(self, text):
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.say(text)
        engine.runAndWait()    

t2s = TextToSpeech()
t2s.textToSpeech("Hello")
t2s.textToSpeech("How are you")
t2s.textToSpeech("I am fine")


Interestingly pyttsx3 doesn't seem to do a great job when run directly in Python threads. This comment on Github suggests a workaround of just running each one in a separate subprocess. Note that this is a bit hacky and be aware of the costs of running subprocesses, and the differences between threads and processes.
If you put it together it would look like this
import threading
import queue
import subprocess
import time

class TextToSpeechManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._process_queue, daemon=True)
        self.thread.start()

    def add_to_queue(self, phrase):
        self.queue.put(phrase)

    def _process_queue(self):
        while True:
            phrase = self.queue.get()
            if phrase is None:
                break
            subprocess.call(["python3", "speak.py", phrase])
            self.queue.task_done()

    def stop(self):
        self.queue.put(None)
        self.thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tts_manager = TextToSpeechManager()

    # add stuff you want spoken into the queue
    tts_manager.add_to_queue("Hello, this is the first message.")
    tts_manager.add_to_queue("Here's the second message.")
    tts_manager.add_to_queue("And finally, the third message.")

    # Simulate some other work in parallel
    for i in range(50):
        print(f"Main program doing work {i+1}...")
        time.sleep(1)

    tts_manager.stop()

speak.py would actually call the actual API:
import sys
import pyttsx3

def init_engine():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    return engine

def say(s):
    engine.say(s)
    engine.runAndWait()  # Blocks

if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = init_engine()
    say(str(sys.argv[1]))


